Нужна ли точка после кавычек?
Есть следующая фраза: Давай-ка посмотрим... «Когда был основан сёгунат Камакура?». В 1185 году, конечно. Все это знают.
В ней персонаж зачитывает вопрос из учебника, то есть не цитирует человека. Нужно ли в данном случае ставить точку после кавычек?


Точка после кавычек не нужна, так как это прямая речь персонажа, состоящая из нескольких предложений. Одно из предложений является цитатой, поэтому ставятся кавычки.

Когда вообще ставится точка? На этот вопрос есть ответ у Грамоты:
...ставят точку, если цитата не является 
самостоятельным предложением, а выступает как 
часть придаточного (даже если перед 
закрывающими кавычками стоит МНОГОТОЧИЕ, 
ВОПРОСИТЕЛЬНЫЙ ИЛИ ВОСКЛИЦАТЕЛЬНЫЙ ЗНАК): Б. Л. 
Пастернак подчеркивал, что «самое ясное, 
запоминающееся и важное в искусстве есть его 
возникновенье...».



Итак, точка ставится в конце предложения, если цитата не является самостоятельной, а входит в это предложение. Обычно это касается косвенной речи.
